# Non surjectivity implying no solutions to a system of inhomogeneous equations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

In page 66 of *Linear Algebra Done Right*, we are given a system of linear inhomogeneous system of equations:
\begin{align}
        \sum_{k=1}^{n}A_{1,k}x_k &= c_1 \\
        &\vdots \\
        \sum_{k=1}^{n}A_{m,k}x_k &= c_m
    \end{align}

So that's equivalent to $T(x_1,...,x_n) = (\sum_{k=1}^{n}A_{1,k}x_k,...,\sum_{k=1}^{n}A_{m,k}x_k) =(c_1,...,c_m)$, where $T: \mathbf{F}^n \to \mathbf{F}^m$. Then, Axler asks whether there is some $c_1,...,c_m$ such that the system has no solutions. In the explanation, he says "thus we want to know if range($T$) $\neq \mathbf{F}^m$." I'm not sure why knowing this implies whether there is some choice of $c_1,...,c_m$ that makes the system have no solutions, and why that fact is relevant to showing it has no solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\operatorname{range}(T) \ne \mathbf F^m$. By definition of $T$ we hence have $\operatorname{range}(T) \subsetneq \mathbf F^m$.

That is, there exists some $\mathbf c \in \mathbf F^m$ such that $T\mathbf x \ne \bf c$ for all $\mathbf x \in \mathbf F^n$.

Do you see why this means that $\mathbf c = (c_1, \dots, c_m)$ makes the system have no solutions?